# How cavitation depends on temperature?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have read both theories: that high temperature prevents cavitation which is counter-intuitive and that high temperature facilitates cavitation.

Does anyone have any opinion on this matter?

Comment: Where did you read that low temperature facilitates cavitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cavitation occurs when the fluid pressure in the flow drops to the equilibrium vapor pressure at the prevailing temperature.  The equilibrium vapor pressure increases with temperature.  So, with increasing temperature, cavitation occurs at a higher pressure.  So high temperature facilitates cavitation.  As an example, for water at 100 C, cavitation will occur if the pressure drops to 1 atm.

Comment: Chester Miller, one small point: 100 C and cavitation at 1 atm, only applies to pure water.  Other liquids have their own vapor-pressure vs. temperature curve.

Comment: Good point.  I was thinking about water when I said that.

Comment: A small edit to your original response would probably prevent a bit of confusion.

Comment: Just for terminology sake, I don't believe it is considered cavitation if it's purely a consequence of heating.  I believe the low pressure zone has to be forced somehow.  100 degree water at 1 ATM will cavitate,  but it's only considered cavitation if its a localized area effected by it.